# items can be added at the back of the queue and old items are taken off from the front of the queue

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am newbie in Javascript. Currently taking a task in Javascript where I have to work on a queue.Here is the Task:

> Write a function nextInLine which takes an array (arr) and a number
>   (item) as arguments. Add the number to the end of the array, then
>   remove the first element of array. The nextInLine function should then
>   return the element that was removed.

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here

  return item;  // Change this line
}

// Test Setup
var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Display Code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 6)); // Modify this line to test
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
```

> Result should be like this:

- `nextInLine([], 1)` should return 1
- `nextInLine([2], 1)` should return 2
- `nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1)` should return 5
- After `nextInLine(testArr, 10)`, `testArr[4]` should be 10

Comment: You should post this on domyhomeworkforme.com -- stackoverflow.com is for specific questions.  To get help here, you need to post your work.

Comment: You'll be interested in the Array methods `.push` and `.shift`. Research them on MDN, and you should be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this:

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  // Your code here
  arr.push(item);
  var returnable_value = arr[0];
  arr.shift();
  return returnable_value;  // Change this line
}

// Test Setup
var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5];

// Display Code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 10)); // Modify this line to test
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/bf3gu7ho/)**

```js
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
  arr.push(item);
  return arr.shift();
}

console.log(nextInLine([], 1)); // 1
console.log(nextInLine([2], 1)); // 2 
console.log(nextInLine([5,6,7,8,9], 1)); // 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function nextInLine(arr, item) {
// Your code here
arr.push(item);
return arr.shift(); // Change this line
}
// Test Setup
var testArr = [1,2,3,4,5];
// Display Code
console.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 10)); // Modify this line to test
console.log("After: " + JSON.stringify(testArr));
console.log(nextInLine(testArr, 4));
```

Comment: please explain further